# External Relay Server when server is on Blacklist

Tags: exim, blacklist

I have a Server with Cpanel , that is in a network with Blacklist (no way to change the Ip , all dirty ) , what i want to do , is install another server in another network that all emails sended can pass trough it. I dont know exactly the words that i can use to look for something like this. Any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/, https://www.mailgun.com/, https://postmarkapp.com/, etc. They'll all cut you off quickly if you spam, so if that blacklisting is your fault, don't bother.

Comment: I m not sending spam , just normail mails , but the range is on blacklist.

Comment: Then consider one of those options. https://aws.amazon.com/ses/ is another commonly used one. The search term you want is probably "email service provider" or "transactional email provider".

Answer (score 1):

Just buy a VPS on a different provider with clean IP's and set it up as a mailserver. (EXIM, POSTFIX, Etc). Then set up your MX Records on your domain to point to your new mailer server, then set up an SPF record `v=spf1 mx -all`. Then send all your email through that server. When you have it sending and receiving mail, make sure it's configured right by sending an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com`, so you don't ruin your new IPs.  I think that's you're lowest cost option, using sendgrid, mailgun, postmark is going to cost you monthly, but they are great services with great tools that do almost everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install a mailserver that acts as a 'SmartHost' in relation to your Cpan server, and you'll configure all your email to relay through that host.